# Opening a file that includes a space with its default program in command line

Tags: shell, windows-7, command-line

I am trying to open a file that may contain a space via command line through its default program. I read several answers here that unfortunately did not help me solve the problem.

In short, this will work

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Envelope Manager\Dazzling\Dazzling.exe" C:\Users\Public\Documents\Endic\Dazzling\_thelayout.LYT
```

But adding quotes around the filename won't do any good

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Envelope Manager\Dazzling\Dazzling.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Endic\Dazzling\thelayout.LYT"
```

Ideally, I want THIS to work (includes spaces)

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Envelope Manager\Dazzling\Dazzling.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Endic\Dazzling\the new layout.LYT"
```

All I want is open the file which sometimes includes a space with Dazzling.exe presuming that both paths might include spaces.

I saw one answer to a previous post referring to this page:
http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

This did not work

Comment: Why won't adding quotes do any good?  Why did the solution on the page you linked not work?

Answer (score 0):

For me this works on Windows 7:

```
explorer.exe "\some\path\x x.txt"
```

opens `x x.txt` with notepad - e.g. with default association.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work with the program I have. While the program is the default one for LYT files, calling the file will open the associated program without opening the LYT file by default.

Answer (score 0):

If Dazzling is the registered application for .LYT files then just use the start command:

```
start "" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Endic\Dazzling\thelayout.LYT"
```

Comment: The strange thing is double clicking the file would start Dazzling but won't open the LYT file by default, so calling the file itself won't work. Using Dazzling.exe pathtofile seems to work but only when the full path of the filename has no spaces.

Comment: Dazzling isn't following the Windows conventions.  You can use the short path\filename of the data file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - which uses the short pathname.  It can fail due to a bug in the function.

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Endic\Dazzling\_thelayout.LYT"
for %%a in ("%file%") do (
"C:\Program Files\Envelope Manager\Dazzling\Dazzling.exe" %%~sfa
)
```

And this can work by dropping a file onto the batch file.

```
@echo off
set "file=%~1"
for %%a in ("%file%") do (
"C:\Program Files\Envelope Manager\Dazzling\Dazzling.exe" %%~sfa
)
```